# validate phone number on vb.net

Tags: validation, events, phone-number

I have a regular form(not windows form) in Visual Studio using vb.net. I would like to validate the phone field once it looses focus, in the sense when the user tabs out of the field. How do I raise an event? The dropdown doesn't come with lostfocus event?
Thanks.
~ Nita

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method below to validate phone number. Just pass a phone number argument into the method.

```
 Protected Sub txtPhone_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPhone.TextChanged
    If Not IsPhoneNumberValid(txtPhone.Text) Then
        Dim isvalid = False
        lblValidatioMessage.Visible = True
        lblValidatioMessage.Text = "*Invalid Phonenumber"
    Else
        lblValidatioMessage.Visible = False
        lblValidatioMessage.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function IsPhoneNumberValid(phoneNumber As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim chars As Char() = phoneNumber.ToCharArray()
    For count = 0 To chars.GetLength(0) - 1
        Dim tempChar As Char = chars(count)
        If [Char].IsDigit(tempChar) Or "()+-., ".Contains(tempChar.ToString()) Then

            result += StripNonAlphaNumeric(tempChar)
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    Next

    Return result.Length = 10 'Length of US phone numbers is 10
End Function

Private Shared Function StripNonAlphaNumeric(value As String) As String
    Dim regex = New Regex("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", RegexOptions.None)
    Dim result As String = ""
    If regex.IsMatch(value) Then
        result = regex.Replace(value, "")
    Else
        result = value
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

and in your code front

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox></p>
<asp:Label ID="lblValidatioMessage" Visible="False" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: @ACS- How do you display the error message? Can you write it to a label?

Comment: Yes, You can add a label and return validation error in that. I edited my answer. Alternatively, you can use asp.net Custom Validation. You can find more on this here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Control.Validating and Control.Validated events. Basically, the Validating event is designed for validation. If the phone # isn't valid, set e.Cancel = True, and the focus will stay on that field.

> The following code example uses the derived class TextBox and validates an e-mail address that the user enters. If the e-mail address is not in the standard format (containing "@" and "."), the validation fails, an ErrorProvider icon is displayed, and the event is canceled. This example requires that a TextBox and ErrorProvider control have been created on a form.
>   - [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Function ValidEmailAddress(ByVal emailAddress As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean 
  ' Confirm there is text in the control. 
  If textBox1.Text.Length = 0 Then
     errorMessage = "E-mail address is required." 
     Return False 

  End If 

  ' Confirm that there is an "@" and a "." in the e-mail address, and in the correct order. 
  If emailAddress.IndexOf("@") > -1 Then 
     If (emailAddress.IndexOf(".", emailAddress.IndexOf("@")) > emailAddress.IndexOf("@")) Then
        errorMessage = "" 
        Return True 
     End If 
  End If

  errorMessage = "E-mail address must be valid e-mail address format." + ControlChars.Cr + _
    "For example 'someone@example.com' " 
  Return False 
End Function 

Private Sub textBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles textBox1.Validating

  Dim errorMsg As String 
  If Not ValidEmailAddress(textBox1.Text, errorMsg) Then 
     ' Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
     e.Cancel = True
     textBox1.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length)

     ' Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display.  
     Me.errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, errorMsg)
  End If 
End Sub 


Private Sub textBox1_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles textBox1.Validated
  ' If all conditions have been met, clear the error provider of errors.
  errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, how do I add validate and validating event to the control. Also I did not get "canceleventhandler" in the dropdown list. I did this but it is not correct. Partial Class txtPhone
    Public Event Validated As EventHandler
End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function IsPhoneNumberValid(ByVal Number As String) As Boolean

    dim PhoneValid As boolean
    Dim PhoneNumber As String = "^[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{2}-\d{4}$"
    Dim ChekPhone As New Regex(PhoneNumber )
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Number ) Then

        PhoneValid = ChekPhone.IsMatch(Number ) 
 Else
        PhoneValid = False 

    End If

    Return PhoneValid 
End Function

Private Sub txtPhoneNumber_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPhoneNumber.LostFocus

    If Not IsPhoneNumberValid(txtPhoneNumber.Text) Then  
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Phone Number!")
        txtPhoneNumber.Clear() 
        txtPhoneNumber.Focus() 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.